# The installed Reactor does not match the requested one

Tags: python, scrapy, python-asyncio, playwright

I'm trying to run through the examples on scrape-playwrights docs in running the scrolling example on quotes.toscrape.com/scroll and I can't even get to scraping because of a issue with the reactors:

```
URL SPIDER TEST
***********************
SCRAPE STARTED
***********************
2022-08-11 15:47:38 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'} crawled: <Deferred at 0x11ef17e50 current result: <twisted.python.failure.Failure builtins.Exception: The installed reactor (twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor) does not match the requested one (twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor)>>
```

The code is:

```
import csv
import json
import pygsheets
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod
import json
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.utils.reactor import install_reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
import tempfile

def breaker(comment):
    print('***********************')
    print(comment)
    print('***********************')

class UrlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Url"

    custom_settings={
        'DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS':{
            "http": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
            "https": "scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler",
        },
        "TWISTED_REACTOR": "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='http://quotes.toscrape.com/scroll',
            meta=dict(
                playwright=True,
                playwright_include_page=True,
                playwright_page_methods=[
                    PageMethod('wait_for_selector','div.quote'),
                    PageMethod('evaluate','window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)'),
                    PageMethod('wait_for_selector','div.quote:nth-child(11)'),
                ],
            ),
        )
async def parse(self, response):
    page=response.meta['playwright_page']
    await page.screenshot(path='quotes.png',full_page=True)
    await page.close()
    return {'quotes_count':len(response.css('div.quote'))}

print('URL SPIDER TEST')

configure_logging()
settings=get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    breaker('SCRAPE STARTED')
    bug=runner.crawl(UrlSpider)
    reactor.close()
    yield bug

url_list=crawl()
print('crawled: '+str(url_list))
reactor.run()
```

I've been trying to find the solution for hours with no luck, and I'm using CrawlerRunner because I want to automate the code at some point, but even with CrawlerProcess I get the error.

I'm also using custom settings because I've had issues with project setting not being added with get_project_settings, custom settings let's me make sure it's used.

If I remove the setting for twisted reactor in custom settings the spider scraps and yields but the reactor error happens again and it doesn't retrieve anything.

Comment: What version of scrapy do You use?

Comment: Python 3.10.5 and Scrapy 2.6.1

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had this error:

```
scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme 'https': The installed reactor (twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor) does not match the requested one (twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor)
```

I avoided the error by using the install_reactor method:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request, Response
from scrapy.utils.reactor import install_reactor


class PersonalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_crawler"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.example.com"]
    install_reactor("twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install the reactor, but only once per script. Here's what works for me:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.reactor import install_reactor

install_reactor("twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor")


class PropertySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "properties"
    
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.sreality.cz/hledani/prodej/byty"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for property_item in response.css('div.property'):
            yield {
                'title': property_item.css('span.name::text').get().strip(),
                'href': property_item.css('a::attr(href)').get(),
                'image_url': property_item.css('img::attr(src)').get(),
            }

# Run the spider
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "TWISTED_REACTOR" : 'asyncio'
})
process.crawl(PropertySpider)
process.start()
```

Answer (score -2):

In the settings, find and comment:
REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = '2.7'
TWISTED_REACTOR = 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'

These were the last lines for me

Comment: Your answer is very vague. Please write an answer that required no further clarification. [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Anyways, welcome to your StackOverflow journey!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).